# Specifying different axis labels between facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, axis-labels, facet-wrap

I would like to specify the breaks and colors for two facets independently. Is there a way to do this?

Using this code

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0:3, 4, 6, 8)) +
    facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free")
```

I can get add the additional breaks I need on the bottom facet, but I don't want these for the top. In other words, I'd like to have `0, 1, 2, 3` for the bottom plot and `0, 2, 4, 6, 8` for the top plot.

I don't have any idea of how to specify different colors for the labels between facets (let me know if I should open a separate question about the colors).

[image: facets]

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to plot each group separately, then lay out the plots together:

```
library(gridExtra)

p1 = ggplot(data[data$group=="Group1",], aes(x = x, y = y)) +
       geom_point() +
       scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0:3, 4, 6, 8)) +
       facet_wrap(~ group)

p2 = ggplot(data[data$group=="Group2",], aes(x = x, y = y)) +
       geom_point() +
       scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-1:3)) +
       facet_wrap(~ group)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=1)
```

If you can come up with a rule for programmatically deciding the y-breaks, then you can do all the plots at once using `lapply`. Here's a simple example. For your use case, you'll need to see if you can come up with a rule or rules that work for all the plots.

```
# Store all the plots in a list
pl = list()

pl = lapply(unique(data$group), function(i) {
  ggplot(data[data$group==i,], aes(x,y)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ group) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(min(data$y[data$group==i]), max(data$y[data$group==i])), breaks=min(data$y):max(data$y))
})

do.call(grid.arrange, c(pl, ncol=1))
```